# is there a way to check if variable is declared at compile time?

Tags: c++, c

I mean case like this (this is of course false code /idea only/ as I know it doesn't work like that):

```
int main() {
  int my_int = 42;
  #ifdef my_int
    my_int = 43;
  #else
    int my_int = 43;
}
```

I know that c/c++ program cannot see the names of the variables and cannot tell if it was set or not but compiler can do it, and I ask here is there any way to direct compiler to a given action like omitting or inserting a snippet of code when it encounters a situation when there are duplicate declarations in the same block.

Comment: It couldn't be done with a pre-processor statement because the pre-processor does not know that information. Only the compiler could do it. Which it does not.

Comment: If your function is so big that you'd need this, you should really consider splitting it up …

Comment: Are there any in-code "compiler-directives" ?

Comment: What is the intention behind that???

Comment: Please pick a language. C and C++ are two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only thing that can happen when you have duplicate declarations, is a compiler error. It's always ill-formed. And because the pre-processor has no knowledge of variables, you can't use that either.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. And even if there were, using it would go down the path towards madness.

If you know that the declaration of a symbol is conditional on some defined constant, use an `#ifdef` on that constant to decide what to do.

If you don't know what the declaration of a symbol is conditional on, you really should not be messing around with that symbol because obviously it's external to your project.

Comment: Everything misused is a path towards madness.